# log4net with HTTPhandler

Tags: log4net

In my AssemblyInfo.cs I have:

```cs
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile="ReverseProxy.config", Watch=true)]
```

In the bin directory where the handler dll is I have the file ReverseProxy.config with the contents:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" 
        requirePermission="false"/>        
</configSections>

<log4net>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender, log4net">
            <file value="e:\temp\reverseProxy.log" />
            <appendToFile value="true" />
            <rollingStyle value="Size" />
            <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
            <maximumFileSize value="1000KB" />
            <encoding value="utf-8" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.SimpleLayout" />
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>
</configuration>
```

No logging file is written. I have been able to debug the handler and it hits the `Log.Info(..)` line but nothing is written.
I am wondering if the config file is actually being found.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that the config file needs to be in the website directory, not in the bin directory.